# How to navigate with StackNavigator from a test

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

In my React Native project, I am using [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html) for routing.

I am creating one like this:

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator(routeConfig, stackConfig);
```

And using it in my app like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
//some other code
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.props.store}>
                <View >
                    <Navigator />
                </View>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, I added a new screen to my app, in `routeConfig` and I want to check that it gets called.

In my test, I have something like this:

```
const fakeMyRouteCreator = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(myRouteCreator, 'default').mockImplementation((_) => fakeMyRouteCreator);

const wrapper = mount(
   <App store={store} />,
   {testEnvironment: jsdom}
);

//How do I trigger the navigation?!?!

expect(fakeMyRouteCreator).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

Basically, I just want to make the StackNavigator navigate.

From a React component, you could do something like this:

```
   this.props.navigation.navigate("NestedNavigator")
```

However, this is not possible from a test, since I can't access `props`. So how else can I do it?

Note: I tried to simplify the code before posting it because the route has 2-3 higher order components, making the mock more complex. However, that is not relevant since I just want to know how to trigger the navigator.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: mount is not working for react-native. How did you get the wrapper instance from mount